# How do you focus the body element if another element is already focused?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do you place focus on the `body` / `document.body` element programatically, if another element is already focused?

Calling `document.body.focus()` does not seem to work, probably because `body` isn't focusable.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) Says

> The HTMLElement.focus() method sets focus on the specified element, if
>   it can be focused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox both focus the `document.body` element if you first call `.blur()` on the currently focused element, and then call `window.focus()` immediately after.

Full solution (TypeScript):

```
    private focusBody = () => {
        if (document.activeElement instanceof HTMLElement) {
            document.activeElement.blur();
        }
        window.focus();
    };
```